# Effect word embeddings in CNN

Tags: nlp, word2vec, conv-neural-network

When I use a CNN with word embeddings, the CNN filters the areas in n-dimensional space that are important for class classification.  Using pre-processing like stop word removal and steaming logically reduces the training time. But what about the accuracy of the model. Will, it improved? Because normally the CNN should filter the unimportant words anyway.

Comment: What happens to your accuracy scoring, when you try it both ways?

Comment: I've not tried that yet. I'm more interested in the theoretical side of it

Comment: There's rarely a general answer to your question – "will the accuracy of my process be improved if I do preprocessing step X?" – without consideration of many factors you haven't shared. What's the type/quality/amount of data? What exact preprocessing – which fixed list of stop-words? Or some other frequent-word dropping? And if you meant 'stemming', which approach on which language? Which CNN? And which definition of 'accuracy' in what kind of classification problem with what label quality? Whether step X helps may depend on any of those, & others, so best is usually to try it both ways.